# In a Text File Find and Delete a specific text and Move the content to its immediate parent (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a text file like this:-

```
Word1
(C)
Word2
Word3
```

I want to Delete the line containing (C) and Move that (C) to its immediate Parent like this:-

```
Word1 (C)
Word2
Word3
```

I am working on (Javascript), I want to do this everytime my function generate a txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the File using the built-in [fs api](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). Then filter the contents using [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions) ([Site explaining the one used below](https://regexr.com/7ldef)).
As edge cases are unclear from your question, the regex below generously searches for a "(C)" anywhere on a line and removes it. It does so multiple times if need be.

```js
const fs = require("fs");

const file = fs.readFileSync("./myFile.txt");
const fileContents = file.toString();
const modifiedContents = fileContents.replace(/\r?\n?.*\(C\).*$/gm, " (C)");

console.log(modifiedContents);
```

Input:

```
Word1
(C)
Word2
Word3
```

Output:

```
Word1 (C)
Word2
Word3
```

Input:

```
Wor(C)d1
Word2
Word3
Word4
Word5
Word6 (C)
Word7
Word8
(C)
```

Output:

```
 (C)
Word2
Word3
Word4
Word5 (C)
Word7
Word8 (C)
```

Comment: Thanks for this immediate reply, saved my time